# Add import to module_map or umbrella header

Tags: cocoapods

I wonder If there exists any way to change the content of `PodName-umbrella.h`?
Or somehow to pass my own through podspec DSL.

I need to add import to umbrella header or ideally change all content to this:

```swift
// PodName-umbrella.h
@import MyAnotherPod;
```

Also, I can use a custom `module_map`.
But I couldn't figure out how to use the correct path to the header file from my pod.

```swift
framework module PodName {
    header "MyAnotherPod.h" // ⛔️ Header 'MyAnotherPod.h' not found
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the way, I found the solution!

I created the custom **umbrella header** — `MyPod/Sources/MyPod-umbrella.h`.
And added imports of pods which I want to be available with import `MyPod`:

```objectivec
@import MyAnotherPod;
```

Then I created the custom **modulemap** — `MyPod/MyPod.modulemap`:

```cpp
framework module MyPod {
    umbrella header "MyPod-umbrella.h"
    export *
}
```

And finally in `./MyPod.podspec`:

```rb
# Add MyPod-umbrella.h to sources
s.source_files = "#{s.name}/Sources/**/*.{swift,h}"

# Select custom module map
s.module_map = "#{s.name}/#{s.name}.modulemap"
```

After these changes I just can write:

```swift
import MyPod
// And it also imports MyAnotherPod like
// import MyAnotherPod
```